# For loop and await keyword

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a for loop working with await keyword, it's for retrieving apps to fill a 2D array:

```
 // initial a 2D array
  const filteredGameApps: InstalledApp[][] = []; 

  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    // get apps by Id
    const apps = await getSuggestedGameAppsById(suggestedGameAppIds[i]);

    let filteredApps = apps.filter(
      app =>
        highlyRecommendations.some(highlyRecommendation=> highlyRecommendation.id === app.id)
    );

    filteredApps = filteredApps.slice(0,6);

    filteredGameApps[i] = filteredApps;
  }
```

It doesn't work, it only works if the for loop is removed, for example:

```
    const filteredGameApps: InstalledApp[][] = []; 
    const i = 0;

    // get apps by Id
    const apps = await getSuggestedGameAppsById(suggestedGameAppIds[i]);

    let filteredApps = apps.filter(
      app =>
        highlyRecommendations.some(highlyRecommendation=> highlyRecommendation.id === app.id)
    );

    filteredApps = filteredApps.slice(0,6);

    filteredGameApps[i] = filteredApps;
```

Did I miss anything here?

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? What do you expect happens? What happens instead?

Comment: always use a `for of` loop when using `async/await`

Comment: @PRSHL why do you think it makes a difference?