# For of loop contains Await keyword

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a for of loop here but it seems not work with Await keyword

```
  const gameApps: InstalledApp[][] = [];
  const indexes = [0, 1, 3, 4];

  for (const i of indexes) {
    const apps = await getGameAppsById(
      suggestedGameAppIds[i]
    );

    let filteredApps = apps.filter(
      app =>
        !highlyRecommandations.some(highlyRecommandation=> highlyRecommandation.id === app.id)
    );

    filteredApps = filteredApps.slice(0,6);

    if (filteredApps.length < 3) {
      filteredApps = [];
    }
    gameApps[i] = filteredApps;
  }
```

It only works if I deleted the for loop, for example:

```
  const gameApps: InstalledApp[][] = [];
  const i = 0;

    const apps = await getGameAppsById(
      suggestedGameAppIds[i]
    );

    let filteredApps = apps.filter(
      app =>
        !highlyRecommandations.some(highlyRecommandation=> highlyRecommandation.id === app.id)
    );

    filteredApps = filteredApps.slice(0,6);

    if (filteredApps.length < 3) {
      filteredApps = [];
    }
    gameApps[i] = filteredApps;
```

Am I missing anything here? Any idea is appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For loop and await keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69357553/for-loop-and-await-keyword)

Comment: Same as [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69357553/for-loop-and-await-keyword) - you still haven't provided a [mcve] or explained what the problem is.